# show/hide when hover, then how to stay shown when clicked?

Tags: jquery, function, click, hover, show-hide

If I have a jquery script that shows and hides an element when hover, how do I make my element thats supposed to hide stay displayed if I click on it?

```
$(selector).hover(function(){
//this shows the element on mousein
     $(element).show();
     $(element).click(function(){
            $(this).css({'display':'list-item'});
     });
},function(){
//this hides element on mouseout
     $(element).hide();
}
```

The reason its list-item, its because this element I'm clicking is a `<li>` tag. I believe this is why it should be `list-item` and not `block`? Also, When I just do `alert($(element).css('display'));` within the click function, it shows list-item.

Comment: you're adding the click handler on each hover... the code should be something like: `$(selector).hover(function(){...}, function(){...}).click(function(){...});`

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your click handler, you can unbind the hover event after showing the element:

```
$(element).click(function(){
    $(this).css({'display':'list-item'});
    $(selector).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

declare a another click event handler and toggle the element.

```
$(selector).click(function(){
     $(element).toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class stating whether or not the element has been clicked.

```
$(element).click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('clicked');
});
```